# How to Debug Redirect Loops in flask

Tags: python, web, flask, brython

This question is not really about any specific code, but I am using flask and I would like to know what are the best ways to debug redirect loops as they do not appear as errors in either the werkzeug or the browser terminal. Any response is appreciated, especially additional reading material.